# Oracle 11g Enterprise Manager Login Fail Internal Error has Occured

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have installed Oracle 11g on my Windows 10 machine. I followed [all preinstallation requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/reqs.htm).

When trying to log in to the Enterprise manager via this link:

```
https://localhost:1158/em
```

I get the error:

> Internal Error has occurred. Check the log file for details.

I have found log files and it looks like this is the relevant entry:

```
2017-09-17 07:36:53,631 [MetricCollector:HOMETAB_THREAD600:60] ERROR rt.DbMetricCollectorTarget _getAllData.344 - java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getURL(EMDClient.java:1570)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getConnection(EMDClient.java:1266)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getConnection(EMDClient.java:1242)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getResponseForRequest(EMDClient.java:1689)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getMetrics(EMDClient.java:981)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.rt.DbHomeTab._getAllData(DbHomeTab.java:340)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.rt.DbHomeTab.getData(DbHomeTab.java:154)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCached.collectCachedData(MetricCached.java:416)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCollectorThread._collectCachedData(MetricCollectorThread.java:605)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCollectorThread.run(MetricCollectorThread.java:325)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

I have tried to set the unique name in environment variables, I thought maybe Java was the problem so I updated my JDK to 8. I am still getting the same error, and my SQL Plus will not open, as soon as I put in the correct credentials it closes. Also I have configured a Listener and tested, test was successful.

Comment: you need to make sure all environment variables are set properly and your database is working properly

Comment: After installing Oracle, there was a warning:
Error starting database control, please execute the following commands:
1) Set the environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME to Database unique name
2) C:\OracleInstallation\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\emctl.bat start dbconsole

I have done so, are there other environment variables to set? I also set the environment variable ORACLE_HOSTNAME to my PC name. The bat file in step 2 closes as soon as its opened.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue, turns out it was a time zone issue. The DB time zone and computer time zone were different. Thus the DB Console would not start and was giving the error "EM daemon is not running".
I fixed it by following [instructions](http://vishalorcl.blogspot.com/2012/01/em-daemon-is-not-running-dbconsole.html) here.

Also note before I did that I completely uninstalled Oracle and reinstalled it. There were some issues on that install that were causing SQL not to run. But the above is what fixed the Internal Error I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SYSMAN database user is not locked.

```
select username, account_status from dba_users where username = 'SYSMAN';
```

If the account status is not OPEN then

```
alter user SYSMAN account unlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting dbconsole

```
$ emctl stop dbconsole
$ emctl start dbconsole
```